# How to get proper color format

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my editor I have a label and on UITapGestureRecognizer I need to get the text color of the text

```
NSLog(@"Fontcolor---- %@",sanlabel.textColor);
```

but this code returning me

```
UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.686275 1 1 1
```

how do I get the color code in proper format so that I could us it as

```
UIColorFromRGB(0X2c3836)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method (taken from [here](http://softteco.blogspot.jp/2011/06/extract-hex-rgb-color-from-uicolor.html)):

```
- (NSString *) htmlFromUIColor:(UIColor *)_color {

if (CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(_color.CGColor) < 4) {    
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(_color.CGColor);    
_color = [UIColor colorWithRed:components[0] green:components[0] blue:components[0] alpha:components[1]];    
}

if (CGColorSpaceGetModel(CGColorGetColorSpace(_color.CGColor)) != kCGColorSpaceModelRGB) {    
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#FFFFFF"];    
}    
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%02X%02X%02X", (int)((CGColorGetComponents(_color.CGColor))[0]*255.0), (int)((CGColorGetComponents(_color.CGColor))[1]*255.0), (int)((CGColorGetComponents(_color.CGColor))[2]*255.0)];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are setting the text of the label, which is some colour definition of some kind, and you then later want to know which label was tapped?

I think this is the wrong approach, and a better approach is to use the tag of the label to index into an array of the colour definitions.  This is both quicker and allows you to change the text format of the label later (perhaps for internationalization) without affecting functionality.

So assume there are 3 labels; define the colours of each label:

```
static unsigned _labelColours[3] = {
    0x2c3836, 0x2c3837, 0x2c3838
};
```

Now set the 3 label's tags starting at 100 (say).  This can be done in code or within IB.

And then when you want to know what the colour assigned to the label is, simply do this in the action method:

```
- (IBAction)labelWasTouched:(id)sender {
    NSInteger tag = [sender tag];
    NSAssert(tag >= 100 && tag <= 102, @"Tag out-of-range");
    unsigned colour = _labelColours[tag - 100];
    UIColor *colourObj = UIColorFromRGB(colour);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily multiply each values from UIDeviceRBGColorSpace by 255. And then use NSString::stringWithFormat to convert the values to HEX with %x.

Also:

```
int r, g, b, a;

r = (int)(0.686275 * 255);
g = b = 1*255;

NSString *hexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x%x%x",r,g,b];
```

Comment: NSLog(@"Fontcolor---- %@",sanlabel.textColor); returning me the color format then how could I get 0.686275 as a individual .

Comment: You got 2 values when the Color is created by [UIColor colorWithWhite:] all over´s give u 4 values. Than split the String and convert the 4 (or 2) parts to int.

But it´s a little dirty.....

Comment: I have tried [getcolor componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] but it gives me exception

Comment: wow. Ok here is some code:

NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lblTest.textColor];
NSArray *components = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        
int r, g, b;
        
r = [[components objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
g = [[components objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
b = [[components objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
        
r *= 255;
g *= 255;
b *= 255;
        
NSString *hexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x%x%x",r,g,b];
        
NSLog(@"test: %@ | %i %i %i",hexStr,r,g,b);

Comment: Mirko Brunner I figured it out .. Here is the ans  components=CGColorGetComponents(sanlabel.textColor.CGColor); 
r = (int)(components[0] * 255);
    g = (int)(components[1] * 255);
    b = (int)(components[2] * 255);